invalid hook call, one works but the other does not
I am trying to modularise my code so im trying to separate the data that is being read
here is my previous code that works without error:
function Home({navigation, route}): React.JSX.Element {
   const [showAddBillModal, setShowAddBillModal] = useState(false)
   const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
   const backgroundStyle = {
      backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
    };

    const toggleShowAddBillModal = () => {
       setShowAddBillModal(!showAddBillModal)
  }

   // const user = getLoggedInUser() //works

    return (...)

but when i try to modularise it by separating the user data read into another file/class:
login page:
const login = (text, navigation) =>{
let userData = getLoggedInUser(text)
if(userData !== null || userData !== undefined){
    () => navigation.navigate('Home', {user: userData})
}
}

function Login({ navigation }): React.JSX.Element {
const [name, onChangeNameText] = React.useState('');
const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
};

// const user = getLoggedInUser()
return (....
                <Pressable
                    style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                    onPress={() => login(name, navigation)}
                    >...
)
}

file to read data:
export default getLoggedInUser = async (name) => {
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
// const userData = null
try{
    console.log("test")
    await firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.data().name == name) {
                    setUserData(doc)
                    // return doc
                    // userData = doc
                    // return userData
                }
            });
        });
        return userData
}
catch(error){
    console.log(error)
}
}

i get invalid hook call here
i have tried normally doing "function name() {hook ....}" but it also gives the same error, its working everywhere except this part

I don't think the first code should work either since it's neither a React component nor custom React hook. Are you just trying to convert the code in the first example into a custom React hook? Or something else? The second code example looks like entirely different code, so it's unclear how the two snippets relate and what you are trying to do.

edited to hoefully make it clearer

solved it, my stubborn mind did not think of placing the usestate hook at the front for 3 whole days :D
login page:
function Login({ navigation }): React.JSX.Element {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
    const login = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("presslogin")
        //   const user = await getLoggedInUser(name, setUserData);
        await getLoggedInUser(name, setUserData)
        // console.log(user)
        //   if (user) {
            navigation.navigate('Home', { userData });
        //   }
        } catch(error) {
          // handle/ignore/etc
        }
}

backend:
export default getLoggedInUser = async (name, setUserData) => {
try {
    const users = await firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
                if (doc.data().name == name) {
                    setUserData(doc);
                }
            })
    });
    // return userData;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // re-throw for callers
    throw error;
}
}

i will be accepting my own answer but for anyone who wants to see a solution with custom hook see Drew Reese's answer :)
edit: usestate did not work for me in the end as its asyncronous... updated answer below:
login page:
function Login({ navigation }): React.JSX.Element {
const [name, onChangeNameText] = React.useState('');
const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
};
const login = async () => {
    try {
        const userData = await getLoggedInUser(name)
        if(userData){
            navigation.navigate('Home', {userData})
        }
    } catch(error) {
      // handle/ignore/etc
    }
}

backend:
export default getLoggedInUser = async (name) => {
let userData = null
try {
    await firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
                if (doc.data().name == name.toLowerCase()) {
                    userData = doc
                }
            })
    });
    return userData;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // re-throw for callers
    throw error;
}
}


You cannot call React hooks outside React components or custom React hooks as this breaks the Rules of React Hooks.
You could convert your getLoggedInUser function into a React hook so that it can also use the useState hook. I'd suggest returning a function the UI can call to initiate the data fetching from your firestore backend.
Example Implementation:
export default useGetLoggedInUser = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  const getLoggedInUser = async (name) => {
    try {
      const users = await firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .get();

      let userData = null;
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data().name == name) {
          setUserData(doc);
        }
      });
        
      return userData;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      // re-throw for callers
      throw error;
    }
  };
  
  return {
    userData,
    getLoggedInUser,
  };
}

Move the login handler into the Login component to close over name and navigator in callback scope. Call your new useGetLoggedInUser hook and access the returned getLoggedInUser function, to be called in the login callback. await its return value, and if truthy, issue the navigation action.
function Login({ navigation }): React.JSX.Element {
  const [name, onChangeNameText] = React.useState('');
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const { getLoggedInUser } = useGetLoggedInUser();

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await getLoggedInUser(name);

      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate('Home', { user });
      }
    } catch(error) {
      // handle/ignore/etc
    }
  };

  return (
    ...
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
      onPress={login}
    >
      ...
    </Pressable>
  );
}


the export default useGetLoggedInUser is still not working, due to the second line "useState" though i dont know why its not showing any error now, console.logging before the usestate declaration works but not after

oh i see what you mean now.... i have never tried to create a custom hook before and it was never on my mind to do so, this solution should work too
